# How to Handle Circularly Dependent Classes in Python

Tags: python

I have two classes `Img` and `ImgAnalyzer` each in their own module. `ImgAnalyzer` accepts an `Img` object as a parameter and performs various analyses on it, but I want to have the `Img` object to 'own' the `ImgAnalyzer` object, ie if I want to use the analyzer, I need to use it through the image.

ex:

*img.py*

```
from img_analyzer import ImgAnalyzer
class Img:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do thing
        self.analyzer = ImgAnalyzer(self)
    # other funcs
```

*img_analyzer.py*

```
from img import Img
class ImgAnalyzer:
    def __init__(self, img: Image):
        # do thing
    # other funcs
```

Then I could access the analyzer from the image:

```
img = Img(params)
img.analyzer.func()
```

This inevitably causes a circular import error.
The classes should be in separate files because they have different functions and are too long to reasonably combine anyway. I looked around here and on other sites but couldn't figure out how to fix it.
How can I have a class operated through and dependent on another class without causing errors?

Comment: Does `ImgAnalyzer` actually need to import `Img`?  It seems likely that everything the analyzer does, it does via a method or attribute of an `Img` object that was passed to it - which doesn't require an import.

Comment: @jasonharper Isn't the way I structured it bad practice though? And, if I need to check that the parameter passed is an `Img` object for error handling for example, I would need the import statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, don't.

Circular imports are already a bad enough attempt at sharing code between two files/modules. It seems like you want something more like an include directive found in other languages but even then circular include causes errors. Your case is compounded by the fact that you have circularly dependent instances. Circular class instantiation is *legal* in Python, but it's messy and can't be split into separate files.

In your case it seem like you're using `ImgAnalyzer` as an extended methods package for `Img`; you even call it as such `img.analyzer.func()`. You can accomplish the same functionality by decoupling the classes from each other and making the import one-way. The identity of each instance of `ImgAnalyzer` was completely dependent on an instance of `Img`, so once we decouple that, we don't even NEED a class:

```
# img_analyzer.py

def func(img):
    # do stuff on img, intended to be Img instance
```

```
import img_analyzer

class Img:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do thing
    # other funcs

pic1 = Img(params)
img_analyzer.func(pic1)
```

Syntactically it does not look like `Img` owns `img_analyzer` or `func`, but it didn't in your original code either. `func` used to belong to the `ImgAnalyzer` class and could be used like `ImgAnalyzer.func(ImgAnalyzer(img), img)`, for which `img.analyzer.func()` was just syntactic sugar. `img_analyzer.func(pic1)` is just as neat and concise while avoiding circular dependency. `func` still belongs to `Img` in the sense that it was designed specifically for `Img` instances.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only need to import `Img` in `img_analyzer.py` for the type checking

You can use the typing module's TYPE_CHECKING constant

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from img import Img

class ImgAnalyzer:
    def __init__(self, img: 'Image'):
        # do thing
    # other funcs
```

[Per the `typing` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING), `typing.TYPECHECKING` is a special constant that is assumed to be `True` by 3rd party static type checkers. It is `False` at runtime